# Sort by highest number inside the loop

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

Is it possible to sort by highest number inside the loop? I am using `WP_Query` and inside it I have a custom query to get the total number of companies on each data. I already get the total number on each data but my problem now is that How can I sort them from highest to lowest. Here is my sample code below:

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'stacks');
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
      $the_query->the_post();
       $exact_curr_id = '"'.get_the_ID().'"';
            $get_companies = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID as company_ID, post_title as company_name, post_status as company_status FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts tbl1 
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as tbl2 ON tbl1.ID=tbl2.post_id AND tbl2.meta_key = 'vendor-featured'
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as tbl3 ON tbl1.ID=tbl3.post_id AND tbl3.meta_key = 'vendor-ap'           
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as tbl4 ON tbl1.ID=tbl4.post_id AND tbl4.meta_key = 'vendor-as'


            WHERE (tbl1.post_type = 'company-stacks' AND tbl1.post_status = 'publish'
            AND tbl2.meta_value LIKE '%$exact_curr_id%'
            OR tbl3.meta_value LIKE '%$exact_curr_id%'
            OR tbl4.meta_value LIKE '%$exact_curr_id%')

            GROUP BY tbl1.ID", OBJECT);

            $group_companies = array();
            $get_company_count = 0;
            if($get_companies){
                foreach($get_companies as $company){
                    //group each company id
                    $group_companies[] = ($company->company_ID);          

                }
                if($group_companies){
                    //count total each group
                    $get_company_count = count($group_companies);

                }   
                //Need to sort here by highest number to lowest
                if(!empty($get_company_count)){
                   ?>
                   <h4 class="ms-title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h4>
                   <p class="total-companies">Number of companies (<?php echo $get_company_count; ?>)</p>
                   <?php
                }
            }//end get company count
    } // end while
} // endif

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: You should do your sorting in SQL otherwise you will need to build the array in PHP first before you can sort it. You cannot sort as you traverse the array.

Comment: So it's not possible to sort inside the array. The only option for now is to build an array. Thanks Sherif